# Cast Exception when using a Comparable array on Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, casting

I'm trying to add methods to change the priority of an element on a process binary heap that is a non generic Class, but it is a subclass of a generic one. The problem appears when I try to assign a `Comparable` array element which is casted to a generic type `T` to a `Process` variable I get a  `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Comparable; cannot be cast to [Ltp07.ejercicio3.Proceso;`. Consider that I was asked to declare the array as `Comparable` and cast it to `T` to bypass java not allowing to declare a generic array.

I have:

```
public class MaxHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> implements PriorityQueue<T> {

    @SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
    protected T[] data = (T[]) new Comparable[100]; 
    protected int elementsAmount = 0;

//some class methods
```

}

Then there is this simple user defined class `Process` that is declared as `public class Process implements Comparable<Process>`

And:

```
public class ProcessQueue extends MaxHeap<Process> {

public void decreasePriority (int position, int decrement) {
    Process temp;
    if (position > 0 && position <= elementsAmount) {
        temp = data[position];      //this is the line that generates the cast Exception
        temp.setPriority(temp.getPID()- decrement);
        data[position] = temp;      //and I guess probably this line will generate another one if the execution reach this point
        percolateDown(pos);         
    }

//some other methods

}
```

So my question is how can avoid this Exception without changing the MaxHeap Class implementation if possible (this is for academic purpose and I am expected to do this in this way)?  and also, trying to go beyond to what my teachers asked me, is a good practice to do what I done in the second sentence of the MaxHeap class, casting to Comparable to be able to have a generic array? what about if I try to implement a data structure generic class were the objects aren't expected even to be comparable, I will have to cast it to Object, that sounds even worse, or there is another way to solve this kind of issue?

EDIT:

the error appears at runtime when decreasePriority()` is called and it reaches the marked line

Process class is declared as: `public class Process implements Comparable<Process>` and the compiler, in case it is related with the solution, doesn't allow me to declare it as `public class Process implements Comparable` complaining that Comparable is a raw type and references to generic type Comparable should be parametrized.

Comment: Copy pasted your code and after changing `implements PriorityQueue<T>` to `extends PriorityQueue<T>` works fine (with what you posted here)

Comment: I can't do that with the complete source code, PriorityQueue is an interface, and I don't think that the problem is too much related with that interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array's actual runtime type is `Comparable[]`, which is not assignable to `T[]` (unless `T` is exactly `Comparable`), so the cast is not theoretically correct. This "lie" doesn't cause any problems as long as `data` is only used within the inside of `MaxHeap`, where `T` is erased to `Comparable`.

However, if you expose `data` as type `T[]` to an outside scope where `T` is expected to be a specific type, then that will cause cast exceptions. In this case, the `protected` variable `data` is exposed to the subclass `ProcessQueue`, which specifies a specific type (`Process`) for `T`. So it expects `data` to be a `Process[]`, but it isn't. That causes the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because one item in `data` is not a `Process`.

What this means is that the items in the `Comparable` array are not `Processes`.  You haven't shown us the class declaration, nor where you create the processes. This seems to be important.

You need your processes to be declared

```
class Process extends ... implements Comparable {
}
```

and you need to initialise the array with the new processes somewhere, e.g.

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++) data[i]=new Process();
```

Comment: I just added the `Process` class declaration to the original post, the `Process` class is a pretty basic class with just a few getters and setters, the only remarkable thing about it is that it extends `Comparable` thus it have a `compareTo()` method, the instanciation of it is pretty much trivial. In respect to the initialization of the array, the instantion of the array elements is correctly made through an `addElement()` in the `PriorityQueue` Class which mainly resolves it through the superclass `MaxHeap`